# jQuery Mobile compatible grid that allows scrolling of tbody

Tags: jquery-mobile, grid

I need to place a fixed height table inside a jQuery Mobile application. If there are more rows than the height of the table, the body of the table should become scrollable. I just tried the jqGrid plugin inside a jQuery mobile page and it is not showing the scrollbar. Has anybody successfully integrated any one of the popular grids (jqGrid, Flexigrid, SlickGrid, DataTables etc.) with jQuery mobile?

P.S. I found a jQuery Mobile version of jqGrid [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/mobile/), but it seemed terribly slow on my Android device. Wonder if anone else has had a similar experience.

Comment: did you try [jQuery Mobile layout grids](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-grids.html)?

Comment: I don't mean layout grids - the context here is data tables. I did not find a good answer anywhere, so I have started a mobile grid evaluation project on Github: https://github.com/archfirst/mobile-grid-evaluation. Please feel free to contribute.